# Using results from a query/data source as a parameter in another query with SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm looking for the best way to use the results from one query into another query, which uses a different server and database.  I have to OLE DB sources set up. The first source will give me a list of 12 digit long numbers that I will need to use in my second query as a filter. Example

1st OLE DB Source:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
digits
from foo
```

2nd DB Source

```
SELECT DISTINCT
numbers
from abc
where numbers IN
(select digits from 1st DB Source)
```

I do not have any DBA access to sp's, so they are out of the question. What is the best way to approach this? I'm not sure if there is a way to output the results from the 1st source into a variable so that my second query could use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I'm not sure if there is a way to output the results from the 1st source into a variable so that my second query could use it.*

YES ! You can. Here is a step wise demo.

**1**: I have created 2 sources(source2012, source2014) and a variable (varResult) which stores value returned by my `Execute SQL Task` connected to source2012. As depicted below, set Result set tab to store value returned by SQL query.
[image: img1]

**2**: In second `Execute SQL Task`, I have used `?` to pass parameter in sql query connected to second source.

[image: img2]

**3** : Parameter mapping is set as below so that `?` is mapped to ResultSet `variable` during run time.
[image: img3]